# How can I match the missing values (nan) of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

how can I set all my values in df1 as missing if their position equivalent is a missing value in df2?

```
Data df1:
Index     Data
1          3
2          8
3          9


Data df2:
Index     Data
1          nan
2          2
3          nan

desired output:
Index     Data
1          nan
2          8
3          nan
```

So I would like to keep the data of df1, but only for the positions for which df2 also has data entries. For all nans in df2 I would like to replace the value of df1 with nan as well.

I tried the following, but this replaced all data points with nan.

```
df1 = df1.where(df2== np.nan, np.nan)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), which is doing exactly the inverse of `where`:

```
df3 = df1.mask(df2.isna())
```

output:

```
   Index  Data
0      1   NaN
1      2   8.0
2      3   NaN
```

In your case, you were setting all elements matching a non-NaN as NaN, and because equality is not the correct way to check for NaN (`np.nan == np.nan` yields `False`), you were setting all to NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Change `df2 == np.nan` by `df2.notna()`:

```
df3 = df1.where(df2.notna(), np.nan)
print(df3)

# Output
   Index  Data
0      1   NaN
1      2   8.0
2      3   NaN
```